# Using a custom latex export class in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to get rid of some packages in the header of the latex files exported by org. [This](http://orgmode.org/tmp/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html) tutorial suggests that the following be added to the configuration of `emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
      '("org-article"
         "\\documentclass{org-article}
         [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
         [PACKAGES]
         [EXTRA]"
         ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
         ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
         ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
         ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
         ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

However, when I start `emacs`, I get the error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: org-export-latex-classes
```

I also tried putting the following in my `.org file`:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent
  (add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
          '("per-file-class"
             "\\documentclass{scrartcl}
             [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
             [EXTRA]"
             ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
             ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
             ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
             ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
             ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
#+end_src

#+LaTeX_CLASS: per-file-class
```

However, when I export, `org-mode` complains that there is no class named `per-file-class`.

How do I work around this difficulty? (please note that I do not possess any `lisp` background)

Comment: this is answered in http://superuser.com/questions/896741/how-do-i-configure-org-latex-classes-in-emacs

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the (add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes ....) *after* the loading of ox-latex.el (which is where the variable is defined. One way to do that is to use eval-after-load:

```
(eval-after-load 'ox-latex (add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes ...))
```

For the per-file class, you need once again to have ox-latex loaded and then you need to evaluate the code block with C-c C-c. Check the value of org-export-latex-classes using C-h v afterwards to make sure it's "taken".

Comment: Thanks, from a newbie. In which class will each heading and subheading  be formatted into?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but here's my stab at an answer: In whichever class you specify with `#+LaTeX_CLASS: `, therefore in the `perf-file-class` above.